Spring data unique constraint on columns with null value
I'm using MySQL and on my db I have an entity object and i want to add a constraint on 2 columns.
I have 2 columns that should be unique:

resource_name : string (non null)
entity_id : foreign key (nullable)

I want to be able to create a resource in db with same resource name but this value must be unique depending on entity id. I added the follow annotation
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "resources",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "uniqueEntityAndResourceNameConstraint",
                        columnNames = { "entity_id", "resource_name" }
                )
        }
)

The issue is that the constraint do not allow me to persist resource with same resource name when entity id is null... Is there a solution for this ?

You didn't indicate which database you are using but you can try a function-based index:
create unique index uniqueEntityAndResourceNameConstraint on resources(case when entity_id is not null then resouce_name end, entity_id);

or
create unique nonclustered index uniqueEntityAndResourceNameConstraint on resources(resource_name, entity_id) where entity_id is not null;

You will have to create this index manually, not via annotations.

I should have specify i was on mysql ... I'll consider adding it manually
